# Ansible getting error to convert it into json

Tags: json, ansible, aws-cli

I am using below code to get lambda tags and trying to convert the output to json, but get below error. Looks like to_json is not working as expected. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? I need to get the tags for lambda functions

```
- name: Lambda - Retrieve existing instances
  block:
  - shell: aws --region {{ AWSRegion }} lambda list-functions | jq -r ".Functions[].FunctionArn" | xargs -I {} aws --region {{ AWSRegion }} lambda list-tags --resource {} --query '{"{}":Tags}'
    register: LambdaClustersTagR
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ aK }}"
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ SK }}"
  - debug:
      var: LambdaClustersTagR
  - set_fact:
      LambdaClustersTag: "{{ LambdaClustersTagR.stdout | from_json }}"
```

Error message a follows:

```
TASK [deployment/Lambda : set_fact] ********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'LambdaClustersTag': u'{{ LambdaClustersTagR.stdout | from_json }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Extra data: line 9 column 1 - line 33 column 2 (char 397 - 1491)\n\nThe error appears to be in '/var/lib/deployment/Lambda/tasks/main.yml': line 14, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      var: LambdaClustersTagR\n  - set_fact:\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Please find below the result of shell command execution, I need to convert below response into json

```
TASK [deployment/Lambda : debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "LambdaClustersTagR": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "aws --region us-east-2 lambda list-functions | jq -r \".Functions[].FunctionArn\" | xargs -I {} aws --region us-east-2 lambda list-tags --resource {} --query '{\"{}\":Tags}'", 
        "delta": "0:00:04.791855", 
        "end": "2021-08-22 18:17:18.046849", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2021-08-22 18:17:13.254994", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "{\n    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:sam-app-HelloWorldFunction-RVdw5VaehZNq\": {\n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/sam-app/366f4e20-ba7b-11eb-8e29-06942b403bc4\", \n        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"sam-app\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"HelloWorldFunction\"\n    }\n}\n{\n    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:pouConfigFunction_te\": {\n        \"applications\": \"pr2\", \n        \"env\": \"te\"\n    }\n}\n{\n    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:PaymentBatchTopic\": {}\n}\n{\n    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:te-pou-config2-pouConfigFunction-XoXhZK1OCL1z\": {\n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/te-pou-config2/347ee360-f12f-11eb-b87c-0aee4f45e49a\", \n        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"te-pou-config2\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"pouConfigFunction\"\n    }\n}\n{\n    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:te-pou-config-test-pouConfigTestFunction-DM2B0dZF0JuW\": {\n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/te-pou-config-test/b6ac3610-f127-11eb-9513-0a79740bc2e0\", \n        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"te-pou-config-test\", \n        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"pouConfigTestFunction\"\n    }\n}", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "{", 
            "    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:sam-app-HelloWorldFunction-RVdw5VaehZNq\": {", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/sam-app/366f4e20-ba7b-11eb-8e29-06942b403bc4\", ", 
            "        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"sam-app\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"HelloWorldFunction\"", 
            "    }", 
            "}", 
            "{", 
            "    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:pouConfigFunction_te\": {", 
            "        \"applications\": \"pr2\", ", 
            "        \"env\": \"te\"", 
            "    }", 
            "}", 
            "{", 
            "    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:PaymentBatchTopic\": {}", 
            "}", 
            "{", 
            "    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:te-pou-config2-pouConfigFunction-XoXhZK1OCL1z\": {", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/te-pou-config2/347ee360-f12f-11eb-b87c-0aee4f45e49a\", ", 
            "        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"te-pou-config2\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"pouConfigFunction\"", 
            "    }", 
            "}", 
            "{", 
            "    \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345:function:te-pou-config-test-pouConfigTestFunction-DM2B0dZF0JuW\": {", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-id\": \"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12345:stack/te-pou-config-test/b6ac3610-f127-11eb-9513-0a79740bc2e0\", ", 
            "        \"lambda:createdBy\": \"SAM\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:stack-name\": \"te-pou-config-test\", ", 
            "        \"aws:cloudformation:logical-id\": \"pouConfigTestFunction\"", 
            "    }", 
            "}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted content does not reference `args`, are you sure you have given the whole story? It would be especially helpful if you didn't edit the error message, choosing instead to include the contextual details that ansible gave to you

Comment: @mdaniel Updated the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

Your output contains several top level json mappings one after the other, e.g.

```json
{
  "a_var": "value",
  "other_var": [1,3,4]
}
{
  "some_other_var": "toto"
}
{
  "yet_an_other_var": "titi"
}
```

This makes the `from_json` filter a bit nuts and I have to admit the error message is really far from clear (I spent quite some time finding the issue myself).

You will have to either load each top level json mapping on its own or generate a single top level mapping containing all your vars that you can load at once, i.e.

```json
{
  "a_var": "value",
  "other_var": [1,3,4],
  "some_other_var": "toto",
  "yet_an_other_var": "titi"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, How to create single top level mapping?

Comment: What have you tried for that and what is the problem you have?